# What are the threat vectors against Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In doing research on "Chrome Extensions Security" most of the results are about the extensions themselves being threats (malware, etc.).

If I write an extension to be used with my web application, what are the security threats against the extension (not from the extension)?  Is the extension secure against malicious attacks?  Can the code running in the extension be compromised?

It is interesting that there is not a "Security" section in the Chrome Extensions [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) nor is the word "security" mentioned in the Chrome Extensions [FAQs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq).

Comment: If the extension doesn't sanitize the input from the user or any external source, it has a security hole. If the extension loads external libraries even from trusted sources a mitm proxy can redirect those to a malicious script. Overall I'd say a lot of generic security considerations apply to extensions, nothing specific really stands out.

Comment: Is there any way that my background.js can be hacked (accessed and modified)?  If I infer from the Google docs correctly, the background,js does not run in the browser's sandbox for web page, the background.js runs in the application scope of the browser itself and is therefore more insulated than "normal" JavaScript.  Is that correct?

Comment: Just like one tab cannot hack another tab that runs a page from a different URL origin. The only theoretically possible method is a Spectre-based attack but it'll be so slow that I don't think it could be practically implemented as it would have to hack through both native machine code of Chrome and V8 byte code.

Comment: @wOxxOm if you use Subresource Integrity when loading external js (or css) this will prevent mitm proxy type attacks. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: Yeah, all these problems have known solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This video from December of 2009 answers one of my major concerns:  [Google Chrome Extensions: Content Scripts and Isolated Worlds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laLudeUmXHM)

Aaron Boodman, an engineer at Google, presents content scripts, one of the features of Google Chrome's extension system, as well as the concept of **isolated worlds** (keeping content scripts isolated from each other and from the pages they are running on).

Good quote from the video:  "Since no JavaScript objects are shared between 'Isolated Worlds', it is not possible for web page JavaScript to use the shared DOM to break out of the normal web page sandbox and somehow get access to the content script or its APIs."

Good image from the video: [Isolated Worlds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVUpq.png)

If you have any other good references on Chrome Extensions Security, please post in a comment to this question.  Thx.